# Is missing define the type when export the interface in mobx-state-tree?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state-management, mobx-state-tree

I try to create two model and store in order to more well manage the mobx-state-tree

The example in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-moon-fr6j6?file=/src/store/booking-store.sample.ts

Here is the error message:

Argument of type '{ booking: Booking[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ModelCreationType<ExtractCFromProps<{ id: ISimpleType; bookingServices: IArrayType<IModelType<{ id: ISimpleType; name: ISimpleType; }, {}, _NotCustomized, _NotCustomized>>; }>>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'booking' does not exist in type 'ModelCreationType<ExtractCFromProps<{ id: ISimpleType; bookingServices: IArrayType<IModelType<{ id: ISimpleType; name: ISimpleType; }, {}, _NotCustomized, _NotCustomized>>; }>>'